# How to create a strong-named assembly?

Tags: asp.net, assemblies

I have a web site project in which my architecture is an N-layered architecture. I am using Micorsoft Enterprise library's validation DLL file. As of now this DLL file is not strongly named. I need to make that assembly strongly named. How can I do this?

I saw some articles which depicts how to create a strong-named assembly by taking the Visual Studio 2008 command prompt and type:

```
sn -k publickey.snk
```

Then add the assembly tag to the `assemblyinfo.cs` file. I tried to do that, but my website project dosen't have any `assemblyinfo.cs` file.

Comment: You should be able to do this via the project properties dialogue on the project containing the Enterprise Library's source I think.

Comment: I got one link.
 [msdn](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/ff8eedb6-18ca-40b6-8c06-b0ecff19a90e)
Please have a look at this.

Answer (score 1):

Since ASP.NET web site projects are compiled dynamically, you can't assign a strong name to the assembly since it does not exist (yet). If you want to assign a strong name your ASP.NET code, you'll have to use a ASP.NET web application project instead.

As for assigning a strong name to a third-party DLL, you can't unless it's been delay signed. There is [another way](http://buffered.io/2008/07/09/net-fu-signing-an-unsigned-assembly-without-delay-signing/), but it will probably **contravene** the license agreement.

Comment: As far as I know the Microsoft Enterprise Library comes with source so you can compile it yourself.

Comment: In that case, it should be trivial setting the properties to sign the Enterprise Library project with a strong name. However, I think the ASP. NET Website project can't be strongly named since there's no assembly created.